# SQL WHERE Clause Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Having a Friday moment...trying to write MySQL criteria as follows:

A timestamp between two dates
ALSO, the timestamp is not greater than 23:59 if field2 is a or b

Something like:

```
(`timestamp` BETWEEN @StartDate And @EndDate) AND NOT ((`timestamp`>='23:59') AND (`Field2` NOT IN ('a','b')))
```

This looks a bit off to me, and is showing the error character in my editor, so I'm trying to determine if this form is wrong, or if I've miscounted parentheses somewhere. I'm actually performing some calculations on the timestamp field, but have omitted those for simplicity's sake.

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: remove the `not` from the not in ('a','b') also timestamp >= string 23:59?  how many hours are there in a day?  so you are excluding the last 59.9999 seconds?

Comment: Good catch on the not. Actually I am excluding the last 59 seconds intentionally, which is why I have to have the fields a and b part - the system feeding the data is unreliable in the last minute before the switchover.

Comment: Then I just think the not was the only thing in error based on requirements as I understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than trying to avoid `OR` for indexing purposes anything wrong with something like this?

`... AND (f2 NOT IN ('a', 'b') OR ts <= '23:59')`

Edit1: *(if I remember my boolean logic transformations correctly)* it is equivalent to:

`... AND NOT (f2 IN ('a', 'b') AND ts > '23:59')`

Edit2: or, to look at it another way, the first version can be expanded to this:

`... AND (f2 NOT IN ('a', 'b') OR (f2 IN ('a', 'b') AND ts <= '23:59'))`

Comment: I need to exclude records with either a or b values, and greater than 23:59. It is possible for a or b values to exist prior, and I need those.

Comment: It should work then; it includes all non-"a or b" and anything (including "a or b" that have a ts <= 23:59). _see edits for more explanation_

Comment: Can you check your operators please? The OP has `timestamp >= '23:59'` which you inverted to `ts <= '23:59'` then inverted to `ts > '23:59'`.

Comment: @onedaywhen OP's operators were, as he stated himself, "a bit off"; as far as inverting from `<=` to `>`; `A OR B` <=> `NOT(NOT A AND NOT B)`.

Comment: Fair enough. Your logic rewrite is sound, BTW, and clever too!